# Drawing triangles in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, trigonometry

I am developing a simple game that involves a sprite being able to throw out a rope. To implement this I want the user to click a spot on the screen, and calculate the angle between the clicked spot (target) and the player sprite position (origin). From this I can easily draw a right triangle, and I then want to constrain the triangles hypotenuse to represent the "rope" has a limited length.

To do this, I get the original triangles angle, define its hypotenuse as the rope's length, and then use cosine to work out the shortened x length and sine to work out the shortened y height.

I am using SKShapeNodes to draw temporary triangles while I try to figure this out:

```
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
CGPoint target = newAnchorPoint; //This the the clicked spot
CGPoint diff = CGPointMake(target.x - origin.x, target.y - origin.y);
double angle = atan2(diff.y,diff.x);
double kLength = 400;
double newXLength = cos(angle) * kLength;
double newYLength = sin(angle) * kLength;
CGPoint newTarget = CGPointMake(newXLength, newYLength);

tPath1 = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(tPath1, NULL, origin.x, origin.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(tPath1, NULL, target.x, origin.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(tPath1, NULL, target.x, target.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(tPath1, NULL, origin.x, origin.y);
tri1.path = tPath1;

tPath2 = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(tPath2, NULL, origin.x, origin.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(tPath2, NULL, newTarget.x, origin.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(tPath2, NULL, newTarget.x, newTarget.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(tPath2, NULL, origin.x, origin.y);
tri2.path = tPath2;

ang.path = nil;
CGMutablePathRef curve = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(curve, NULL, origin.x, origin.y, 100, angle, 0, YES);
ang.path = curve;
```

The problem with this is that it works perfectly when the origin is 0,0. Once the origin moves from this point, the second, constrained triangle does not match the original. I have checked and rechecked my math and made sure I understand the trigonometry but I cannot understand why this is not behaving as expected. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation of `newTarget` produces the vector that would represent the length of the rope. Conversely, `target` is a location.

I would imagine you want:

```
CGPoint newTarget = CGPointMake(newXLength + origin.x, newYLength + origin.y);
```